# How to fix the negative position value on div?

Tags: html, css, angular

Please Look at the Snippet Image below

[image]

I created a div that has `position:fixed;` and noticed a white space on left side that is taking by `position 15`, I am seeing it for the first time.How to fix it.

How to change the `position`to 0.

```html
<div class="nav-color" style="position:fixed; z-index: 5; bottom: 0; padding: 10px; background-color: blue; " class="col-md-12">
  <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Type Here" style="margin-right: 10px;" />
  <span class="input-group-btn col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-default " type="button" style=" margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 10px;">Add</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning " style="color: white;">Logout</button>
      </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You are required to post an example of your markup here: [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I solved this issue by adding `left:0;right:0;`

Comment: You need to write that as an answer to your question, not just make it a comment.

Answer (score 0):

As i noticed that just by making `bottom:0;` the whole element is sticking to bottom,  I added `left:0;` and It corrected the position to left.
Provide value according to which side the gap is.
`left:0;right:0;`